# Наилучшее среднеквадратичное приближение функции

Tags: математика

В университете изучаем сейчас построение и программную реализацию наилучшего среднеквадратичного приближения. Преподаватель дал два вопроса:

1. Построить СЛАУ при выборочном задании степеней аргумента полинома φ(x) = a0+a1*x^m+a2*x^n, причем степени n и m в этой формуле известны.
2. Решить задачу из вопроса 2, если степени n и m подлежат определению наравне с коэффициентами  , т.е. количество неизвестных равно 5.

Первую задачу я решила следующим образом:
[image: Текс]

Второй вопрос вызывает затруднения. Прошу помочь разобраться.